# Confusion with attr_accessible and signup forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessible

For a Rails project I'm working on, most of the information in a user's model is meant to be confidential, such as a two factor auth phone number.

I've only whitelisted the basics in the model, `email`, `password`, and `password_confirmation`.

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a sign-up form for this sort of User, when only a few attributes are able to be set via mass assignment. Is there some way to specify a normal set of `attr_accessible` properties, and a second set that are only accessible when creating a new User instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is. In whatever controller action your form posts the form data to, just directly set non-whitelisted values of your model from values in `params`:

```
def create
  user = User.new(params[:user]) 
  user.phone_number = params[:user][:phone_number]
  ... <other non-whitelisted attribute assignments> ...
  user.save!
end
```

That will work even if `phone_number` is not in the list of whitelisted attributes (i.e. even if it does not appear in the arguments to `attr_accessible` in the `User` model). You can do the same for any other non-whitelisted form attributes.

Comment: Apparently my brain turned off, because I completely forgot about regular setters. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessible is on the class, so you can always re-open the class and define it again:

```
class User
    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

That would go in whichever controller method you want. When you're done, you can re-open the class again and set a new attr_accessible.

That's horrible, though. Instead you should look at the definition of attr_accessible and try to do what it does directly. Maybe.